# How to use html encoded characters to perform XSS?

Tags: xss, html, encoding, xssi, filter

I am trying to perform XSS but to get out of the context and write the payload I need to use Angle brackets and the angle brackets are html encoded. I tried double encoding technique with url encoding+html encoding, url encoding+url encoding and html encoding+html encoding but none worked. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked up the OWASP guide to this? https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: This is a pure programming question. I suggest to move it to SO.